# StackOverflow error when using ORM inside a transaction

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

If I put any sort of ORM operations inside a transaction, I get an error.

Setup: `CentOS 6`, `MySQL 5.6` and `Lucee 4.5.1`.

Code

```
<!--- stuff here is fine --->
<cftransaction>
    <cfscript>
        qryInsert = EntityNew("Game");
    <cfscript>
</cftransaction>
```

or

```
<cfscript>
//stuff here is fine...
transaction{
    qryInsert = EntityNew("Game");
}
</cfscript>
```

Entities

League.cfc

```
component persistent="true" table="Leagues"{
    property name="leagueID" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="User" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="User" fkcolumn="userID";
    property name="LeagueTournamentType" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="LeagueTournamentType" fkcolumn="leagueTournamentTypeID";
    property name="leagueName" ormtype="string";
    property name="leagueAbbr" ormtype="string";
    property name="teamName" ormtype="string";
    property name="gameInMinutes" ormtype="int";
    property name="deleteYN" ormtype="boolean";
    property name="showReportYN ormtype="boolean";
}
```

Season.cfc

```
component persistent="true" table="Seasons"{
    property name="seasonID" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="User" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="User" fkcolumn="userID";
    property name="name" ormtype="string";
    property name="deleteYN" ormtype="boolean";
    property name="showReportYN" ormtype="boolean";
}
```

User.cfc

```
component persistent="true" table="Users"{
    property name="userID" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
    property name="username" ormtype="string";
    property name="pwd" ormtype="string";
    property name="email" ormtype="string";
    property name="Language" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Language" fkcolumn="langID";
    property name="createdDate" ormtype="timestamp";
    property name="lastLoginDate" ormtype="timestamp";
    property name="activatedYN" ormtype="boolean";
}
```

Error in question:

```
Lucee 4.5.1.022 Error (java.lang.StackOverflowError)
Message     java.lang.StackOverflowError
Cause   java.lang.StackOverflowError
Java Stacktrace     java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.(HashMap.java:1411):1411
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.(HashMap.java:1456):1456
    at java.util.HashMap$Values.iterator(HashMap.java:959):959
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:180):180
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryData.getDataSources(SessionFactoryData.java:314):314
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMSession.getDataSources(HibernateORMSession.java:850):850
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl.add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:111):111
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getORMSession(PageContextImpl.java:3138):3138
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:59):59
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:55):55
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.accessors.CFCGetter.get(CFCGetter.java:71):71
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230):230
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.java:66):66
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852):3852
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80):80
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190):190
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147):147
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219):219
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99):99
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMTransaction.begin(HibernateORMTransaction.java:40):40
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMConnection.(ORMConnection.java:61):61
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMDatasourceConnection.(ORMDatasourceConnection.java:52):52
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl._add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:122):122
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl.add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:113):113
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getORMSession(PageContextImpl.java:3138):3138
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:59):59
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:55):55
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.accessors.CFCGetter.get(CFCGetter.java:71):71
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230):230
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.java:66):66
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852):3852
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80):80
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190):190
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147):147
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219):219
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99):99
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMTransaction.begin(HibernateORMTransaction.java:40):40
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMConnection.(ORMConnection.java:61):61
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMDatasourceConnection.(ORMDatasourceConnection.java:52):52
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl._add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:122):122
```

A few refresh later...

```
Lucee 4.5.1.022 Error (java.lang.StackOverflowError)
Message     java.lang.StackOverflowError
Cause   java.lang.StackOverflowError
Java Stacktrace     java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.entries(IdentityMap.java:93):93
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:179):179
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:92):92
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMTransaction.begin(HibernateORMTransaction.java:40):40
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMConnection.(ORMConnection.java:61):61
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMDatasourceConnection.(ORMDatasourceConnection.java:52):52
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl._add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:122):122
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl.add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:113):113
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getORMSession(PageContextImpl.java:3138):3138
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:59):59
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:55):55
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.accessors.CFCGetter.get(CFCGetter.java:71):71
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230):230
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.java:66):66
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852):3852
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80):80
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190):190
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147):147
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219):219
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99):99
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMTransaction.begin(HibernateORMTransaction.java:40):40
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMConnection.(ORMConnection.java:61):61
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMDatasourceConnection.(ORMDatasourceConnection.java:52):52
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl._add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:122):122
    at lucee.runtime.db.DatasourceManagerImpl.add(DatasourceManagerImpl.java:113):113
    at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getORMSession(PageContextImpl.java:3138):3138
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:59):59
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMUtil.getSession(ORMUtil.java:55):55
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.accessors.CFCGetter.get(CFCGetter.java:71):71
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230):230
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.tuplizer.AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizerImpl.java:66):66
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852):3852
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80):80
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190):190
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147):147
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219):219
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99):99
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
```

**Update #1**

Using any sort of ORM code or trying to load any entity, will yield this error.

I do have an entity for `Game`, I failed to paste the relevant code.

I changed the entity and get the same errors:

```
transaction{
    qryInsert = EntityNew("Game");
}
```

Got a new error this time though, before refreshing and falling into the same stack traces specified earlier.

```
Lucee 4.5.1.022 Error (java.lang.StackOverflowError)
Message     java.lang.StackOverflowError
Cause   java.lang.StackOverflowError
Java Stacktrace     java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852):3852
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80):80
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190):190
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147):147
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219):219
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99):99
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50):50
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206):1206
    at lucee.runtime.orm.hibernate.HibernateORMTransaction.begin(HibernateORMTransaction.java:40):40
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMConnection.(ORMConnection.java:61):61
    at lucee.runtime.orm.ORMDatasourceConnection.(ORMDatasourceConnection.java:52):52
```

**Update #2**

ORM settings:

```
<cfset THIS.ormEnabled = true>
<cfset THIS.datasource = "abc">
<cfset THIS.ormSettings = {logsql = true, cfclocation="entity", dbCreate = "none", dialect = "MySQLwithInnoDB"}>
<cfset THIS.invokeImplicitAccessor = true>
```

**Update #3**

Solution, adding `autoManageSession` in my ORM settings:

```
<cfset THIS.ormSettings = {logsql = true, cfclocation="entity", dbCreate = "none", dialect = "MySQLwithInnoDB", autoManageSession = false}>
```

Comment: What are your ormsettings in Application.cfc?

Comment: @cfsimplicity see update #2 with orm settings from application.cfc...

Comment: You might also want to check out the Lucee bug database for this kind of error. Not sure if it is relevant, but a very quick search turned up a [similar issue #233 for 4.5.1](https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-233?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the error may be related to this [known issue](https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-233):  To work around it, try adding `autoManageSession=false` to your ormsettings.

Comment: @cfsimplicity In my transaction, I have entitySave(), transaction commit and then ormflush()... the entity isn't present in my db afterwards

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you gave, you're trying to load a 'Game' entity, which you don't have defined (or at least didn't include).  I suspect that the stacktraces you're getting are coming from it trying to dump too much data.

What happens if you try something like:

```
<cfscript>
transaction{
        qryInsert = EntityNew("Season");
        qryInsert.setName('testing');
        EntitySave(qryInsert);
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: My bad, didn't paste the matching entity. I do have a Game entity. See update #1, which shows the usage of an entity specified in my post. Anything related to ORM in a transaction and it fails (even a simple ORMExecuteQuery fails). I must have done something really wrong to get this faith because not being able to use ORM in a transaction is odd.